# Prime chains with large gaps

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-gaps

It is well known that the gap between consecutive primes is unbounded. Is this 
still true for a chain of consecutive primes ?

More Formally : Is the following statement true for all natural numbers m and n ?

There are m consecutive primes $a_1,...,a_m$ , such that all the gaps are greater
than n (this means $a_{k+1}-a_k>n$ for all k with 1 <= k <= m-1) ?

I also heard about primes in arithmetic progressions, but I always wondered if
the primes must be consecutive in such progressions.

Can any of the known properties of the prime-numbers help to answer this question ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, this is known.  It feels a bit like squashing a fly with a B-52, but there is a beautiful theorem of [Shiu](http://jlms.oxfordjournals.org/content/61/2/359.abstract) (*Strings of Congruent Primes*, 2000) which seems to cover everything you want.  A direct consequence is that for any $n,m$ the following is true:

> There are $m$ consecutive primes $a_1,\ldots,a_m$ that are all congruent to $1$ mod $n$.

So not only are the gaps between these primes at least $n$, but they all lie within a prescribed arithmetic progression.  (It's important not to confuse this with $a_1,\ldots,a_m$ *forming* an arithmetic progression: a result of such strength is not yet known.)

EDIT: Another approach is the following: for any fixed $n$ let $P_n$ be the set of primes whose gap to the next prime is $\le n$.  It is known from sieve theory that the number of primes in $P_n$ up to $x$ is $O(x/\log^2 x)$, with the constant certainly dependent on $n$.

Since this set has asymptotic density zero relative to the sequence of primes, there must be arbitrarily long clusters of primes that do *not* lie in $P_n$ (if there were no clusters of length $m$ then the lower relative density of $P_n$ would be at least $1/m$).

Comment: Erick, do you have a reference for the theorem of Shiu ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: @RodneyColeman See D. K. L. Shiu, "Strings of Congruent Primes", J. London Math. Soc. (2000) 61 (2): 359--373.  http://jlms.oxfordjournals.org/content/61/2/359.abstract